# How to update the array of data in a single record using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need one help. I need to update array of data into a single record for different column using PHP and MySQL. I am explaining my table and code below.

> cn_sell_info:

```
sid     name   file1   file2   file3   file4

 1      Raju
```

Here I need to update the four file field. I am explaining my array of data below.

```
$result=
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [img] => abc.png
        [status] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [img] => sdfg.png
        [status] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [img] =>  
        [status] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [img] => 1sqd.png
        [status] => 1
    )

)
```

Here I need whose status is 1 the respective image will update in the file column serially.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$result=array(array("img"=>"abc.png","status"=>1),array("img"=>"sdfg.png","status"=>1),array("img"=>"erty.png","status"=>0),array("img"=>"1sqd.png","status"=>1));
$concate_sql = array();
$inc_ = 0;
foreach($result as $key=>$v){
    $inc_++;
    $img = $v['img'];
    $status = $v['status'];
    if($status==1){
        $concate_sql[] = " `file".$inc_."`='".$img."' ";
    }
}
$added_sql = count($concate_sql)?implode(",",$concate_sql):'';
$update = "update table_name set ".$added_sql." where `sid`='1';";
echo $update;
```

[ https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/php/5.6.16/3RV ]

Output.

```
update table_name set `file1`='abc.png' , `file2`='sdfg.png' , `file4`='1sqd.png' where `sid`='1';
```

Comment: I dont want to update the name only file fields.

Comment: So remove name from query @subhra.

Comment: Can you update your code so that I will upvote you ?

Comment: you should try it out @JaydeepMor has already explained dont expect spoon feeding all the answer